# Getting repeated error to plot using mglearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot

```
import mglearn
mglearn.plots.plot_scaling()
```

But I got the following error:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.six'
```

I did install mglearn using pip install mglearn. I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Have you also installed `sklearn`?

Comment: @SMcQ Yes, I did!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using conda you could try `conda install scikit-learn`

Comment: Did you install it using conda?

Comment: I used pip installed

Comment: That maybe the problem just uninstall sklearn using pip and install it using conda.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to an old version of mglearn. If you do `pip install --upgrade mglearn` you'll probably fix the problem.